# How do I have more than one Recycle Bin on my desktop?

Tags: windows-7, icons, recycle-bin, desktop-icons

I use more than one monitor for my computer. I use Windows 7. I would like to be able to place a recycle bin icon on each screen so that when I can only see the desktop on one screen I don't have to minimize windows on other screens (or use the delete key). I could not find anything about this when trying Google searches on the topic.
Preferably these extra icons would be multiple instances of the same recycle bin.

Is there any way to do this in Windows or with software?

Comment: Would a shortcut to the Recycle Bin on each monitor not be sufficient for your purposes? What do you mean by multiple instances?

Comment: If by shortcut you mean I can drag files into it and have it act just like the normal recycle bin, that would be great!

Comment: I just added a Recycle Bin shortcut to my desktop and was able to drag a file into it. Does it work for you?

Comment: Well, I guess I'm being an idiot today :P Since it isn't like a normal icon I assumed it wouldn't have all the normal options . Shame on me for not checking first. So yup, works just fine. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, I'll post as an answer in case anyone else stumbles upon this and didn't check either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click the Recycle Bin on your desktop and select **Create shortcut**. This will create an additional shortcut to the Recycle Bin on your desktop. Drag this to the monitor you want. It will behave like the Recycle Bin and you can drag files into it as you normally would.